# Assigning JSON value to a Variable that Resides Outside JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, highcharts

I have a question regarding JSON Web Services and AJAX Function. I have declared a JavaScript Function below.

```
function setJsonSer(){

            formData = {
                'Email': 'clientlink@russell.com',
                'Password': 'russell1234',
                'URL': getVaria()
            };

                $.ajax({
                url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                complete: function(data) {
                    alert("This is Set JSON In  "+JSON.stringify(data));
                }

            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
                type: 'GET',
                data: formData,
                complete: function(data) {
                    alert("This is Get JSON Out  "+JSON.stringify(data));
                }
            });

}
```

As you can see I have alert the `JSON.stingify(data)` statement and it gave me the result as I expected.

Now I want to get that JSON response out of that particular function SetJsonSer() to assign to avariable that resides out side the SetJsonSer() function.

I already tried `return JSON.stringify(data))` and JSON.stringify(data) statements but they did not put the result out from the SetJsonSer() function.

The output must grab from a variable like the below.

```
function Load(){
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
setJsonSer();

var labels = new Array();
var values = new Array();
var catogories = new Array();
var arrayOfArray = new Array();

var rowData = "return value of JSON.stringify(data)";
```

This variable will be used as the query to draw a chart using HighCharts. So could you someone give me a clue how to get the result of the SetJsonSer() function?

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a bit mixed up with asynchronous nature of AJAX.

The AJAX event is being fired, but it won't be causing any pause in the execution of your code, as such, you need to implement a callback.

This code isn't particularly nice, but it should give you an idea of how the data needs to be handled.

```
function setJSONSer() {
    formData = {
        'Email': 'clientlink@russell.com',
        'Password': 'russell1234',
        'URL': getVaria()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        complete: function(data) {
            console.log("Successfullly set JSON!");
            getJSONSer();
        }
    });
}

function getJSONSer()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "/APIWebService.asmx/AnalyticsDataShowWithPost",
        type: 'GET',
        complete: function(data) {
            //alert("This is Get JSON Out  "+JSON.stringify(data));#
            Load(data);
        }
    });
}

function BeginLoad()
{
    setJSONSer();
}

function Load(data)
{
    setJsonSer();

    var labels = new Array();
    var values = new Array();
    var catogories = new Array();
    var arrayOfArray = new Array();

    var rowData = "return value of JSON.stringify(data)";
}

BeginLoad();
```

Comment: You are certainly right! I am not familiar with AJAX  asynchronous nature. So that is the issue within me. But however getting to know is the best thing. Thanks I will try this.

Comment: I have a small question in the function Load() `function Load(data)
{
    setJsonSer();

    var labels = new Array();
    var values = new Array();
    var catogories = new Array();
    var arrayOfArray = new Array();

    var rowData = "return value of JSON.stringify(data)";
}` what should I have to put as the values for `var rowData =' ?

Comment: Where should I use this BeginLoad() function? Shall I used it within the Load(Data) Function or within a button?

Comment: I have not declared a `setJSONSer()` but `setJsonSer()` function. So in `BeginLoad()` fucntion the `setJSONSer()` must changed to `setJsonSer()` right?